# Static endpoint of database RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have created stack on cloud formation which is responsible for creating the stack of Application including Backend, Frontend Instances, Load Balancer, Subnets, Database RDS etc. 
During creating Backend Instance, I defined some commands to run my application eg. getting repository from Github, unzip it, and run Scala application. Problem is that Scala requires some environment variables (eg. database cluster endpoint) which I don't have during creating backend application because Database hasn't created yet.

I tried used DependsOn passing as argument Database Resource but it doesn't work, it says that this field cannot be empty - it means that field

```
"OutDBIClusterHostname": {
  "Description": "Hostname of the RDS-Cluster (Database) in Region I",
  "Value": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "ResRootStackDatabaseI", "Outputs.OutDBIClusterHostname"] }
},
```

is empty.

What do you think, is there exists someting like "static endpoint URL?" It could be very easy, before creating stack, I could enter static endpoint to Cloud Formation and backend would know about host of RDS Database. 
 any suggestions how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDS endpoint should be this format.

> CLUSTER_INDENTITY.cluster-xxxxxxxxxx.REGION_CODE.rds.amazonaws.com

xxxxxxxxxx = fixed hex chars for each account. (Same for all RDS endpoint in your account / can not change)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a CNAME record in Route53 and bind it with your DB once it will be created. Since you'll know the 'static' DNS so you can pass it to your Scala app.